# Handling deferred code

Tags: c++, version-control

A bit of functionality that has been mostly implemented has been shelved until a future development phase. The code is not wanted in the current phase, however it will be needed later, so simply removing it isn't an attractive option. Finishing the code is also considered an unattractive option. I'm trying to work out the best way of putting this functionality into cold storage without:

- leaving clutter in the source files
- removing it altogether (as per the wishes of my team)

I don't immediately see the best way of handling this "temporarily" redundant code. Part of me just wants to just tag the code base and rip out the offending code. My rationale for this is:

- when (and if!) we ever go back to this functionality it'll likely need a fair few changes anyway as everything else would have moved on
- littering the code with (what can only become more) broken / incomplete code wrapped in #if 0 feels wrong wrong wrong
- having a tagged point in source control which has context is much more useful should this functionality be reimplemented later

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: What about putting it into a file that is moved to some special directory?

Comment: So what's wrong with taking a tag/branch and then deleting it from trunk?  That's probably what I'd do, given no further information.

Comment: Simply removing it should be *always* an option. That's what source control is for.

Comment: Sounds right... with revision control, you shouldn't really have any large, experimentally commented-out pieces of code; if you need the code in the future, you can always look it up in the previous revision. If it's feasible, you could move all the code into one file, that might make it easier in the future to refactor it to the future needs.

Comment: The best way to handle this will depend heavily on what version control system you are using. In git I'd just put that functionality into a branch (well in fact for my dev style it would already have been on a branch until it was ready for production so this would never even be an issue. ;) ) - Maybe let us know what system you're stuck with and we can give you more concrete advice.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a branch pointing to revision with unwanted code, continue development in master and merge this two branches later, when this code becomes useful again.

Excuse me using git vocabulary, this concept can be easily ported to other VCSes.

Comment: That was my first thought, however I'd imagine further development could cause the two branches to diverge creating potentially nasty scars. I think it would be a manual job.

Comment: Well, there are other ways of handling these problem, but each of them requires manual merging at some point. You can simply copy this file out of your working tree, but, again, merging. You can make a patch that will apply this unwanted code. But again, it won't apply cleanly. (Yes, I would also love my VCS system to resolve conflicts for me.)